# Selecting dynamically created divs by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cant seem to figure out how to do this but I am creating buttons that when clicked add a new div to a page containing a textbox. This works fine but what I then want to do is if the user clicks on the div I want the divs id to be popped up in an alert box. The code is below.

HTML

```
     <table>
     <td>
     <ul id ="firstColumn">
                    <div id="identifier">
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul id ="secondColumn" width="5%">
                    <li><input type="button" class="formCreationButton" id="textAdd"       value="Single line text" /></li>
     </td>
     <ul>
     </table>
```

The jQuery that adds the div and text box is as follows which works fine.

```
   $('#textAdd').click(function() {
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                newdiv.innerHTML = "Textbox " + textBoxCounter + " <br><div id='container "+counter+"' class='container'><li><input type='text' value='TEXT' name='textBox " + textBoxCounter +"onclick='display(this)'></li></div></br>";

                document.getElementById("identifier").appendChild(newdiv);
                textBoxCounter++
                counter++;
            });
```

So everytime I click on the button a new div and text box are created. What I want to do now is when a user clicks on the div an alert box will pop up containing the id of the clicked div. Obviously this is not the only thing I want to do but its the part I am stuck on, below is my attempt.

```
     $(".container > div").click(function(){
                var divID = this.id;
                alert(divID);
                // do other stuff that needs to be done
            });
```

The only thing that happens when I click on a div is that an alert pops up saying "content". I need it to contain something like "container1" or "container2" etc.

Anyway thanks in advance for any help provided, it is greatly appreciated. Pretty new to jQuery so having difficulty with things that may seem simple to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.on` API wil do the trick: http://api.jquery.com/on/ **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/eqDKP/1/

Please also note that the html table has missing `tr` tag.

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
   $(".container > div").on('click',function(){
                var divID = this.id;
                alert(divID);
                // do other stuff that needs to be done
            });
```

Comment: @undefined Thank-you and now soon its my time to sleep cheers +1 to you as well,

Comment: Hm, not sure why but .on is throwing an error, saying "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'". Any ideas why? Also the tr is just missing cause the table is far bigger, cut most of it out to make it easier to read :). Also thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: @PaulChaney if you are using older version of jQuery just replace `on` with `live` then it should work.

Comment: Excellent, that worked a charm, thanks very much to both you guys, I cant +1 you as I am new to the site but I would if I could!. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: @PaulChaney no worries Glad it helped and and I made a demo for you as well : http://jsfiddle.net/eqDKP/1/ lol I will +1 you anyways!

Comment: While `.live()` may work, I'd suggest you try to read up on using `.delegate()` instead, since `.live()` is deprecated. Better yet, just upgrade your jQuery version (current is 1.7.2), and stick to using the delegate flavor of `.on()`.

Comment: Thank you Tats_innit, that's a pretty cool website. Also I will recommend it to the boss Richard Neil llagn but as is I am just a cog in the machine :).

Comment: hm,Sorry to bother you guys with another question but that alert function is called everytime I click on the textdd button instead of just when I click on the div. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: @PaulChaney hiya it must be coz of the way selector is getting bind, flick a jsfiddle and I can take a look `:)` make sure you have replicated your issue in jsfiddle, I am off in 10 mins sooner the better.

Comment: Hm strange, I have my code copied and pasted into http://jsfiddle.net/eqDKP/2/ however the error is not being replicated there.... Must be something to do with my system itself.

Answer (score 2):

you should delegate the `click` event for new created elements:

> .on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler(eventObject) )

```
$(".container").on('click', "div", function(){
     var divID = this.id;
     alert(divID);
});
```